# when i try to run spring boot app with docker server starter but no access

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

when i run the command

docker-compose up --build

in cmd it log Tomcat started on port(s): 8089 (http) with context path '/*****

but when i try to connect to some API in postman it gives me Error: socket hang up

Here is my docker-compose :

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
     build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
     image: 2021.jar
     image: tomcat:9.0-jdk8
     volumes:
      - ./ROOT:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
      - ./repository:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/repository
     ports:
      - '8089:8080'
     environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS= -Ddb.host=localhost -Ddb.catalog=gohybridit_dev -Ddb.port=5432 -Ddb.username=postgres -Ddb.password=123
```

and this my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} 2021.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","2021.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come with this command and solved my problem

```
docker run -d -p portNum:portNum --restart always XXXXX.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are setting port 8089 in your application properties. If you are, either:

a) update the docker-compose to say `'8089:8089'` instead.

b) update application properties to set the port to 8080 (or remove it altogether as this is the default)

Basically, those ports are `<outside container>:<inside container>`. I personally would match all the ports to 8089 per the first option to reduce confusion.

Comment: I already use the same port in  application properties.

Comment: Do you mean you use `8089` in application properties? If yes, then just do option a